# Is the union/substraction of 2 arbitrary functions also a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let f: A → B and g: A → B be arbitrary functions. For each of the following sets, indicate whether it is generally a function again. Justify your statement. Give a concrete counterexample if the set is not a function:

1. f ∪ g
2. f \ g

These are the only information I got and I don't seem to find anything in books or online to answer this. Don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set definition of a function is fairly confusing the first time you see it.  But once you understand this, this question becomes fairly obvious.

As a set, $f:A\to B$, then $f$ is defined to be a subset of $A\times B$ so that for every $a\in A$ there is exactly *one* and one only $(x,y)\in f$ so that $x = a$ and $y\in B$.

So if for any $a\in A$ there will be an $(a,b)\in f$ and an $(a,c) \in g$.  So bother $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ will be $f\cup g$.  But if $b \ne c$ then for $a$ there are *two* $(x,y) \in f\cup g$ so that $x = a$ and $y\in B$. So unless for every $(a,b)\in f$ then $(a,b)\in g$ and and $f = g$, the $f\cup g$ is not a function.

As for a concrete example any $f \ne g$ will do.  Take $f(x) = 2x +3$ ($f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$) and $g(x)=x^2$ ($g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$).  As $f(2) = 7$ then $(2,7) \in f$.  And as $g(2)=4$ then $(2,4) \in g$.  And $(2,4)$ and $(2,7)\in f\cup g$.  And $f\cup g(x)$ is not uniquely defined.

Perhaps for practice in the set definition of a function we should consider $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B= \{a,b,c\}$:

Then $f \subset of A\cup B$ so that $f = \{(1,x),(2,y),(3,z),(4,w), (5,u)\}$ where $x,y,z,w,u$ are each one element of $B$.  That's the definition.  For each $q\in A$ there is one and only one $(q,\omega)\in f$.

SO let's just arbitrarily define $f = \{(1,a),(2,b), (3,c), (4,a), (5,b)\}$.  So that means $f(1) =a; f(2)=b,... etc.$.

And lets define $g \subset A\cup B$ as $g=\{(1,c), (2,b), (3,a),(4,c),(5,b)\}$.

So $f\cup g = \{(1,a),(1,c),(2,b),(3,c),(3,a),(4,a),(4,c),(5,b)\}$... which isn't a function because there are two pairs with $1,3,4$ in the first position.

If we use that second example for the second question:

$f\setminus g = \{(1,a),(3,c), (4,a)\}$.

Although this time this is not a function not because there are two or more cases of pairs with the same first pair, but because for some of the $q\in A$ there aren't any pairs.  There is no $(2,x)$ or any $(5,x)$ in $f\setminus g$ so $f\setminus g: A \to B$ is not a function.

[However $f\setminus g:\{1,3,4\}\to B$ *is* a function.  But part of defining a function is defining the domain.]

=======

**[Upon reflection:  I have changed my mind and believe the answer should be: YES, $f\setminus g:\{1,3,4\}\to B$ *is* a function.  *BUT* it is a function with a domain other than $A$**

=======

To use our first example $f(x)= 2x + 3$ and $g(x) = x^2$ then $f\setminus g = \{(x,2x+3)|x\in \mathbb R; 2x+3 \ne x^2\} = \{(x,2x+3)|x\ne 3; x\ne -1\}$.  This is not a function as $f\setminus g(-1)$ and $f\setminus g(3)$ are not defined.

A third example though, if $f(x) \ne g(x)$ for *any* values of $x$, for example of $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = -x^2$ then $f\cap g = \emptyset$ and $f\setminus g = f$ and $f\setminus g = f$ is a function. (Mush as if $f=g$ then $f\cup g = f$ is a function)

[It might be worth noting that although $f\setminus g$ is not a function in general, from $A\to B$ that $f\setminus g: C\to B$ where $C = \{x\in A| f(x) \ne g(x)\}$ is always a function.  But from a different domain.]

Comment: Since the question is labeled with tag *elementary-set-theory* (where functions are identified with their graphs) it would not surprise if the answer on the second question is just: "yes, it is a function". Indeed not necessarily a function $A\to B$ but in set theory the domain of a function $f$ is *defined* as $\{x\mid\exists y(x,y)\in f\}$ and does not play a part by the definition of the function.

Comment: @drhap.....  Hmmm.... yes, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1)

Let $f(a)\neq g(a)$ for some $a$. If $h=f\cup g$ is indeed a function then what is the value of $h(a)$?

2)

A function $h$ is a set of ordered pairs with the special property that $(a,b),(a,c)\in h$ implies that $b=c$.

Every subset of $h$ is of course again a set of ordered pairs. Will such a subset also have this property?

Observe that $f\setminus g\subseteq f$.

Comment: Re: 2) The empty set is a function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, of course. I will temporarily delete and think of something else. I thought wrongly that it only concerned functions with domain $A$. Thanks for attending.

Comment: In my mistaken answer, I was assuming that f\g was supposed to be a function from A to B, and a function from A has to be defined for every element of A, so if f(x)=g(x) for some x $\in$ A, then f\g is not a function from A to B. But it is a function, just not from A, but a subset of A.

Comment: @Robo300 At first hand I actually made the same mistake as well and gave as (wrong) hint:"what happens if $f=g$?..." See the comment of Arthur on my question.

Answer (score 0):

A function from A to B is a relation from A to B  ( set of ordered pairs belonging to the cartesian product A cross B) in which there are no 2 different ordered pairs with the same first element. In other words, if an ordered pair (x,y) belongs to a functional relation, then there is no ordered pair (x,z) with z diffferent from y.

Let A = {a,b} . Let B={1,2}.

Let f be { (a,1), (b,1) }. The set f is a function from A to B.

Let g be { (a,2), (b,1) }. The set g is a function from A to B.

Now, the union f U g is { (a,1), (b,1), (a,2), (b,1)}.

This union is not a function, since in this new relation, the element *a* is related to 2 different objects : namely 1 and 2.

If it were a function, you could answer the question : " to which unique object is *a* related?" Here one cannot answer, since there is no unique object to which *a* is related.